# How to diagnose a crash that appears to be internal to WebCore (Thread 2, SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, crash, webkit, segmentation-fault

Hello esteemed SO'ers,

A crash recently popped up that's perplexing me. It occurs on `Thread 2`, appears to be internal to `WebCore`, is `Exception Type SIGSEGV` and `Exception Code SEGV_ACCERR`. Full crash log below.

The App uses `UIWebView`s throughout. The main `WebView` displays roughly 30 images that reside on disk, and uses a custom NSURLProtocol to pass messages between native and JavaScript and vice versa.

I'm hoping someone can help me better understand crashes like this (ones that don't point to a particular class/method/line in my code, seem to be inside Apple classes) and how to approach diagnosing and fixing them.

I've read up on `SIGSEGV` and have Googled many variations of info from the crash report. Haven't found anything too helpful yet. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

```
Incident Identifier: [TODO]  
CrashReporter Key:   [TODO]  
Hardware Model:      iPad3,6  
Process:         CurrentTarget [56978]  
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/XXXXXXX-5392-49F5-99AE-XXXXXXXXXXX/CurrentTarget.app/CurrentTarget  
Identifier:      com.xxx.xxxxxxx  
Version:         1.10.7  
Code Type:       ARM  
Parent Process:  launchd [1]  


Date/Time:       2013-07-05 14:38:02 +0000  
OS Version:      iPhone OS 6.1.3 (10B329)  
Report Version:  104  


Exception Type:  SIGSEGV  
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x4  
Crashed Thread:  2  


Thread 0:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3b67ce30 mach_msg_trap + 20  
1   CoreFoundation                      0x332d42bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131  
2   CoreFoundation                      0x332d2fdb __CFRunLoopRun + 819  
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3324623d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356  
4   CoreFoundation                      0x332460c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104  
5   GraphicsServices                    0x36e0133b GSEventRunModal + 74  
6   UIKit                               0x351622b9 UIApplicationMain + 1120  
7   CurrentTarget                       0x0000d6b3 main (main.m:15)  


Thread 1:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3b67d5d0 kevent64 + 24  
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b5b4378 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 36  


Thread 2 Crashed:  
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b1945ca objc_msgSend + 9  
1   WebCore                             0x393d86c9   WebCore::LayerFlushScheduler::runLoopObserverCallback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 25  
2   CoreFoundation                      0x332d4941   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21  
3   CoreFoundation                      0x332d2c39 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 277  
4   CoreFoundation                      0x33246263 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394  
5   CoreFoundation                      0x332460c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104  
6   WebCore                             0x3922a395 RunWebThread(void*) + 445  
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3b5e60e1 _pthread_start + 309  


Thread 3:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3b67ce30 mach_msg_trap + 20  
1   CoreFoundation                      0x332d42bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131  
2   CoreFoundation                      0x332d3031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905  
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3324623d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356  
4   CoreFoundation                      0x332460c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104  
5   Foundation                          0x33b6a5c3 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 255  
6   Foundation                          0x33c0dc45 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
7   CurrentTarget                       0x0002db85 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:162)  
8   Foundation                          0x33c17231 __NSThread__main__ + 973  
9   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3b5e60e1 _pthread_start + 309  


Thread 4:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3b67ce30 mach_msg_trap + 20  
1   CoreFoundation                      0x332d42bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131  
2   CoreFoundation                      0x332d3031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905  
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3324623d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356  
4   CoreFoundation                      0x332460c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104  
5   Foundation                          0x33b9388d +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 309  
6   Foundation                          0x33c17231 __NSThread__main__ + 973  
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3b5e60e1 _pthread_start + 309  



Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State:  
    r0: 0x00000004     r1: 0x39c10f51     r2: 0x000000cc     r3: 0x0ab29439   
    r4: 0x0940c600     r5: 0x1ed70618     r6: 0x1ed70610     r7: 0x0073edf8   
    r8: 0x00000003     r9: 0x00000000    r10: 0x0073ee20    r11: 0x0000008a    
    ip: 0x3cf14568     sp: 0x0073edec     lr: 0x39b7902b     pc: 0x3b1945ca   
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862757/exc-bad-access-sigsegv-in-webcoreusergestureindicatorprocessingusergesture